# Separate data frame into ID columns (with only one unique value), and variable columns (with more than one value)

Tags: r

I have a data frame with several ID cols containing only one unique value and columns that actually contain variables. How to separate those?

I have come up with the following approach using a conditional statement in sapply, but I wondered if there may be a more elegant way to do that?

I am happy with any package, and any output where the data frames are separated, this can also be in a list. Each frame does not need to be assigned to a new object.

```r
mydf <- data.frame(a = 'a', b = 'b', val1 = 1:10, val2 = 10:1)

head(mydf,3)
#>   a b val1 val2
#> 1 a b    1   10
#> 2 a b    2    9
#> 3 a b    3    8

id_cols <- mydf[sapply(names(mydf), function(x) {length(unique(mydf[[x]])) == 1})]

variable_cols <- mydf[sapply(names(mydf), function(x) {length(unique(mydf[[x]])) != 1})]

head(id_cols, 3)
#>   a b
#> 1 a b
#> 2 a b
#> 3 a b

head(variable_cols, 3)
#>   val1 val2
#> 1    1   10
#> 2    2    9
#> 3    3    8
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: A small first step may be to loop over columns instead of over column names. Then you save one `sapply`; `col_ix <- sapply(mydf, function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1)`; `mydf[col_ix]`; `mydf[!col_ix]`. Or use the index to split into a list: `split.default(mydf, sapply(mydf, function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1))`.

Comment: that's true, I was overcomplicating things looping over the names! @Henrik If you don't mind getting some reps for this, you could make this an answer :)

Comment: @henrik `split.default` is crazy. Didn't know this. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very, very slightly shorter way would be

```
Var           = lengths(lapply(mydf, unique)) > 1
id_cols       = mydf[, Var]
variable_cols = mydf[, !Var]
```

Comment: Using `lengths` is a great idea